# MacBook Pro: Battery icon shows as charging even when not connected to power source

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I have a 13" 2017 MacBook Pro no Touch Bar model. It is not connected to a power source but it still shows as charging. While this is not affecting my Mac's performance or anything, but now I don't get that low battery warning when the charge reaches 5% or low, so it just shuts down at 0% without me realising it.

I tried starting it in Safe Mode, but the issue is present there as well.

[image: power info]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of macOS running on your MacBook? Go to System Preferences app → Energy Saver and try toggling Show battery status in menu bar checkbox shown at the bottom.

Comment: Hi @NimeshNeema , I tried that as well but it didn't help. MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.5

Comment: Try cleaning the ports and see if that helps. You should also consider seeking assistance with Apple authorized service provider especially if its covered under warranty.

Answer (score 12):

Welcome to AskDifferent! Try to perform a [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) reset, and possibly also a [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) reset.

From https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295:

> The SMC is responsible for these and other low-level functions on Intel-based Mac computers:
>
> - Responding to presses of the power button
> - Responding to the display lid opening and closing on Mac notebooks
> - *Battery management*
> - Thermal management
> - Sudden Motion Sensor (SMS)
> - Ambient light sensing
> - Keyboard backlighting
> - Status indicator light (SIL) management
> - Battery status indicator lights
> - Selecting an external (instead of internal) video source for some iMac displays

Comment: Tried both. Didn't help :(

Comment: SMC reset didn't work, but NVRAM reset did on my 2017 MacBook Pro 13-inch with 4 thunderbolt ports and touch bar (that is, a MachBookPro14,2).

Comment: SMC worked for me. Mackbook pro 2017 15inch with touchpad

Answer (score 7):

For me I didn't have to do the SMC reset.
On the [SMC reset instructions page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295), these steps were sufficient:

> **Notebook computers with the T2 chip**
>     Before resetting the SMC, try
>   these steps:
>
> Shut down your Mac.
>   Press and hold the power button for 10 seconds,
>   then release the button.
>   Wait a few seconds, then press the power
>   button to turn on your Mac.

I am running on a MacBook Pro with the T2 chip.

Comment: Apple does not explain much about the process (perhaps deliberately), but if it solved the problem for you, this actually did reset the SMC. I need to catch up on the material, but I think the way it worked was either: 1. holding the power button resets the SMC in certain conditions but not others, in which case you need to hold L(⌃+⌥) + R(⇧) and power; or 2. holding the power button resets the SMC, and the alternative method restores the SMC firmware entirely.

Answer (score 6):

For me the SMC reset worked like a charm. Thanks n1000.
For those facing the same problem who don't know how to perform an SMC reset you have to turn off completely your mac, then hold the three keys **Shift** + **Ctrl** + **Alt** (*all on the left side of the keyboard*) + **power button** for 10 seconds, and voilà you can turn on again your MacBook, hopefully solving the problem as it happened to me.

P.s. this SMC reset method is for MacBooks produced before 2018 (T1 security chip); for the T2 security chip the process is slightly different, you can find all the information here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: It worked for me too on a 2017 MacBook Pro with TouchBar.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue here.
I took it to applestore and the voltage sensor was broken. Replacement was quoted €68. Fortunately, warranty covered it.